# What is "&ct=ga"? - Help an SEO determine if URLs containing parameter needs to be redirected

Tags: php, parameters

I am not a developer, just an SEO working with developers.

We are seeing a lot of "&ct=ga" which are all generating a 404 status code. I want to clear these out but before I redirect, does anyone know what it is?

I did a bit of research and it may be connected to some kind of feed (3rd party or Google News). I didn't know if it could be related to Google Analytics (which we use on the site).

**So my question is:**

1. What is this?
2. Is it safe to do a 301 redirect on URLs with this parameter back to the original URL?

Thank you!

Comment: If presence of such a parameter is causing a 404 status code, you should check it with your dev team and I don't think you would need a redirect for it.

Comment: ct=conversion tracking, ga = google analytics

Comment: Thank you. If it were only one 404 page, I would probably ignore since it doesn't seem to come from a "real" user issue. But we are seeing a high number of them and want to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your developers can probably figure out more based on the context. A grep through the PHP code base for `$_REQUEST['ct']` or `$_GET['ct']` should hopefully find something that they can latch onto. Alternatively, if the code is based on a framework, there may be a framework-specific way of getting parameters in the code, in which case they'll want to search for that syntax instead.